# How to remove Java Project Name in URL

Tags: java, eclipse, url-rewriting, glassfish, web.xml

I have this project name in my eclipse 'abc-work' and when I run it on localhost the url is

http://localhost:8080/abc-work

The default file or page that opens is (as per web.xml below)

```
<display-name>abc-work</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>account/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

I successfully deployed this application on a cloud and linked it to my domain.

The URL now is:

http://www.abcwork.in/abc-work/

Now, the problem is -  I need to remove the last `/abc-work/` from this link, login page should directly open with the link `http://www.abcwork.in/`

My project is in Glassfish 3.1.2

I need to make this change, maybe by URL rewriting in web.xml, but I have no clue how to achieve it.

I have tried changing context root from Eclipse project properties, tried changing glassfish-web.xml's context root too - did not work for me.

Any help shall be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? https://alexismp.wordpress.com/2007/08/30/glassfish-tip-have-your-application-be-the-root-application/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** You can set one of your webapps as default. This can be done with the admin console:

*Configuration --> Virtual Servers --> server*

Then select your default web application from the drop-down menu. If your webserver port is 8080, you can start your application now by:

`http://hostname:8080`

instead of `http://hostname:8080/webapp`

Notice that "server" is the name of Glassfish's default virtual server. If you configured a different virtual server for your webapp you need to change it accordingly.

Furthermore regarding [this source](http://www.lubby.org/result.jsf?DB=lkb_linux_english&ID=251), there might be some problems with JDBCRealms.

**Option 2:** You could also deploy your default webapp to "/" instead of "/webapp" but I think the first option is more flexible.

Comment: Perfect, option 1 works for me.   Thanks a million for your help!

Comment: Since the provided solution worked out your problem, it would be nice if you mark the answer as correct as an addition to the million of thanks )

Comment: I have no such and option "Configuration --> Virtual Servers --> servers"